# passing value from iOS native code to cordova

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova

I have some values generated from my native code that I would like to pass to phonegap. These data are generated in real time and are not directly influenced by the user's actions through the phonegap gui.My native code is part of a plugin that I made.

What is the best way to approach this? I want to have a function to send data over anytime and have a listener on the cordova side.  I'm using Cordova 1.5 with Xcode 4.3.

Here is what I have so far:

swipe.js:

```
var swipe={
     callNativeFunction: function (success, fail, resultType) {
    return Cordova.exec( success, fail, 
                        "ca.swipe", 
                        "nativeFunction", 
                        [resultType]); }

};
```

index.html:

```
...

function callNativePlugin( returnSuccess ) {
            swipe.callNativeFunction( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, returnSuccess );
        }

        function nativePluginResultHandler (result) {
            alert("SUCCESS: \r\n"+result );
        }

        function nativePluginErrorHandler (error) {
            alert("ERROR: \r\n"+error );
        } ...  <body onload="onBodyLoad()">     <h1>Hey, it's Cordova!</h1>

      <button onclick="callNativePlugin('success');">Success</button>
      <button onclick="callNativePlugin('error');">Fail</button>

  </body> ...
```

swipe.h:

```
...
@interface swipe : CDVPlugin
- (void) nativeFunction:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
@end
```

swipe.m:

```
...
- (void) nativeFunction:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options {

    NSLog(@"Hello, this is a native function called from PhoneGap/Cordova!");

    //get the callback id
    NSString *callbackId = [arguments pop];
    NSString *resultType = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];     
    NSMutableArray *GlobalArg=arguments;

    CDVPluginResult *result;
    if ( [resultType isEqualToString:@"success"] ) {
       result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString: @"Success :)"];
       //writes back the smiley face to phone gap. 
       [self writeJavascript:[result toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId]];
    }

...
```

The code that I have right now has nothing for doing what I want. I'm not really sure how to setup the code in both cordova and native.

Comment: The approach you describe sounds like a very reasonable way to do it, is that the only question or are you having trouble getting it working?

Comment: @rhooligan I have trouble getting it working, I'm not very familiar with Objective-C and its interaction with phonegap. It would be great to have an example of some sort. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your Objective-C code and then show us your Cordova code?  I wrote some plugins back when it was still called PhoneGap and there are some specific stuff you had to do in the bundle as well as an init sequence you needed to call from JS. The system may have undergone some changes since then though.

Comment: @rhooligan just posted my code, thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you please tell me you got the solution ?
Please post here, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to be able to talk back down to PhoneGap from objective C, in which case you should be able to use something like:

```
 NSString *jsResult = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"hello()"];
 NSLog(@"jsResult=%@",jsResult);
```

And if you have a JS function like "hello" in your index.html like this:

```
function hello(){return "hello";}
```

Its a way of talking back to your PhoneGap web layer

Answer (score 1):

create a class of type **CDVPlugin**

**import #import**  in that class

initialize a handler method .h class

```
- (void)Device:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command;
```

and implement the method in .m class

```
- (void)openDevice:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command{
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = nil;
    BOOL checkOpenDevice=NO;
     pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsBool:checkOpenDevice];
       [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }
}
```

in this way through self.commandDelegate your data will be able to reach to the cordova class 
if the .js file hit(calls) that particular method which is initialized in .h class.